# How anonymous users can un-publish or delete a node with a key based URL?

Tags: views, rules

I am looking for a solution where I can create a special URL (with keys) for each node and when a user (anonymous) visits the node, they can unpublish or delete the node.

There is a module. But it does not work with views.
https://drupal.org/project/node_authlink

any clues or any alternate solution ?

**Clarifications:**

I have more then 10,000 nodes created by admin. i need to generate special access links for all nodes. Once the link is visited the Anonymous user will have permissions to delete the node.

thanks.

Comment: you can create a separate content-type and change the permission for that content-type to anonymous by going to permission page, is that what you looking for?

Comment: No. I already have a content type. and 10,000+ nodes are created with it. I need to generate a "node delete / unpub  link" for each node.

Comment: Try this module, you can set permission based on content type, you don't have to change permission for each node.

https://drupal.org/project/content_access

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for something different . for example: the "unsubscribe link" which  get in the emails to unsubscribe yourself from newsletters. Those links are special links for each user to unsubscribe.

Comment: in that case you can update your question with these details. So that other can understand what you are looking for :)

Comment: If you want to clarify your question, you are supposed to edit your question. This site is not meant as a forum, so don't expect comments to be seen by users judging if your problem is worth their time.

Comment: @FreeRadical, i am not using the site as a forum. The clarifications i added were meant be to for shrish only.